# Non access violation for 2D array using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 2D dynamic array using pointers:

```
int** Grid;
Grid = new int*[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)   { Grid[i] = new int[5]; }
std::cout << Grid[4][300] << std::endl;   // output: -17891602
std::cout << Grid[5][0] << std::endl;     // access violation
```

I need the array to be of a specific size, which is why I am not using a static array.
As you can see, although I am making a 5x5 array, debugger did not give error when trying to read Grid[4][300]. Can someone please enlighten me as to why is this so?

This only appears to be so for the 2nd dimension. (Trying to read Grid[5][0] would give the access violation error) Correct me if I am wrong, but technically I am really creating an array of pointers?

I expect an exception for Grid[5][0]. What I really don't get is why no error for Grid[4][300]. Can someone advise me how do I have a dynamic array with, say dimension of 5x5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c and c++  there is no compilation error as well as runtime error if you tried to access a larger index than declared 
Eg.

> int a[10];
>   std::cout<< a[20];  **// will print some garbage value**

So this answers why **std::cout << Grid[4][300] << std::endl;** is giving output: -17891602 as the second dimension is just array of integers.

Whereas if you declare an array of pointers and tried to access a greater index, then you will get either access violation error or segmentation fault at runtime
Eg.

> int *a;
>   a = new int[5];
>   std::cout<< a[20]; **// will produce segmentation fault**

So this answers why **std::cout << Grid[5][0] << std::endl;** or any value in first dimention greater than declared value will produce an error as **the first dimention should be a pointer to some legal location holding an integer value**
But while trying to access a greater index which might **produce a garbage value which will be an illegal address**, thus resulting in segmentation fault.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @twenty49 the pleasure is all mine.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized Grid[5], in your for-loop you checked for `i < 5`. 
If i is under 5 then it will never be used as 5 inside your for-loop.

Just remember that arrays count 0 as a position.

This means that `int arr[5]` could only be indexed with 0-4, anything more or less would get an **access violation**.

---

The reason why `[300]` isn't throwing an access violation is because your indexing a pointer, rather than a defined array.

---

Also, don't forget to initialize the values in your array (with most probably 0). You might not want unexpected numbers like `-1994021` showing up in your data. 
 [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) is pretty good at doing this.

Comment: yes, i am expecting an exception for Grid[5][0]. What I really don't get is why not for Grid[4][300]. My follow up question will be how do I have a defined array? I cannot use a static array as I need the size of the array to be determined by user-end.

Comment: If it's determined user-end then just keep the length. If you try use `Grid[4][300]` and 300 is over the length then make your own error. "The reason why [300] isn't throwing an access violation is because your indexing a pointer, rather than a defined array."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an array counts 0 aswell. So the very first memory space in the array would be [0][0], provided you initialized it with `for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)`

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int Size = 5;
    int **Grid;
    Grid = new int* [Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        Grid[i] = new int [Size];

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; ++j)
            cin >> Grid[i][j];

    cout << Grid[4][4];
    return 0;
}
```

If you put this into your IDE and compile it, it should print the value of the very last element. That is because you have the following places of the array:

```
Grid[0][0];
Grid[0][1];
Grid[0][2];
Grid[0][3];
Grid[0][4];
...
Grid[4][4];
```

Also keep in mind in dynamic allocation of any kind of an array, you must also provide a delete [].

So the code I placed would correctly look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int Size = 5;
    int **Grid;
    Grid = new int* [Size];
    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        Grid[i] = new int [Size];

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; ++j)
            cin >> Grid[i][j];

    cout << Grid[4][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        delete [] Grid[i];
    delete [] Grid;
    return 0;
}
```

This is because you are working with a Stack. -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

I hope this clarifies some things for you. Best of luck!